# Access Flask context variables from included or imported Jade templates?

Tags: flask, pyjade

I'm using flask with pyjade for templating. I can access context variables within templates directly, and even in inherited templates, but not when I include mixins or try to import mixins from another template. Here's the example:

My Flask application serves this page:

```
def home():
    return render_template('index.jade', foo='bar')
```

So, `foo` is in the context now. Now let's say I have the following mixin in `mixins.jade`:

```
mixin m()
    div= foo
```

And in my template `index.jade`:

```
- from 'mixins.jade' import m

div= foo
+m()
```

In the template itself, I can read `foo` just fine, but in the imported mixin, I get

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'foo' is undefined
```

Is this a shortcoming of pyjade, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not caused by pyjade but Jinja2...

You have to import the template "with context". [See Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import-context-behavior)

This should work:

```
- from 'mixins.jade' import m with context

div= foo
+m()
```

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for pyjade! While I've got you here, shouldn't `include mixins` work here as well to include all mixins in the file, without having to explicitly import mixins with `from _ import _`? Because it doesn't...

Comment: It should, but that goal was never reached before the repository turned inactive: https://github.com/syrusakbary/pyjade/issues/70